# What is the converse of the triangle inequality?

Tags: geometry, logic, inequality, triangles

It's usual when presenting a theorem to also present its converse. Surprisingly, I've never seen the triangle inequality's converse stated.

Triangle inequality: If the sides of a triangle are a, b, and c, then a + b > c.

The converse of this statement is not obvious to me. I've found two references:

"A type of converse of the triangle inequality holds as well" : http://books.google.com/books?id=EbwNKD0xkUwC&pg=PA12

"A statement often called the converse of the triangle inequality states": http://math.rice.edu/~evanmb/math366spring10/math366hw3.pdf

But they use "a type" and "often called"... And it talks about the existence of a triangle... I'm not sure if it's the converse.

Please explain this to me (I'm **very** confused).

Comment: You say "It's usual when presenting a theorem to also present its converse". What do you mean by that? For example, what is the converse of the theorem "Every differentiable function is continuous"?

Comment: I used it as "often when one presents a theorem he also presents its converse", maybe it's wrong :X. Sorry, English is not my native tongue.

Comment: OK, but still, can you tell me one example when in presenting a theorem, you also present its converse?

Comment: What do you mean by the converse? I think if you can clearly understand that, then your problem may be solved.

Comment: Yes, the converses of Thales' intercept theorem, the Pythagorean theorem, those theorems about congruent triangles, if it's isosceles then... if ... then it's isosceles... Sorry, can't remember in fields other than geometry.

Comment: And what exactly is the converse of the Pythagorean theorem?

Comment: @Sawarnik: We have a statement A -> B, its converse is B -> A.

Comment: 5xum: The converse of the Pythagorean theorem is: In any triangle with sides a, b, c, if b² + c² = a², then the angle between b and c is 90°.

Comment: @Sawarnik: Unfortunately, I can't :(.

Comment: Now I see what you mean by converse. But now I cannot see why you would want a converse of the triangular inequality, since it is not a statement of type $A\implies B$. It is a statement "for any $a,b,c$, statement $A$ holds". There is no structure here to invert.

Comment: @JoãoRimu What do you think part B is from the triangle inequality statement (that one is a little more obvious than the part A)?

Comment: @izœc: I think it is "Being a, b, c the respective lengths of three line segments, if a + b > c". Though I'm not sure...

Comment: Not quite... From your original statement: "If the sides of a triangle are $a$, $b$, and $c$, then $a + b > c$." Part B is what comes after the "then" in the statement. So... part B = ?

Comment: But I can't talk about a, b, c without telling what they are... So I still think it is "Being a, b, c the respective lengths of three line segments, if a + b > c". Though I'm not sure...

Comment: Well, you establish what $a,b,c$ are in part A - part B is what must follow from the statement $P$. So... part B is that $a+b > c$. In part A, you lay out all the various conditions that B follows from.

Comment: As discussed above, the *converse* of $p \rightarrow q$ is $q \rightarrow p$. In order to formalize the Euclidean theorem, we need variables $a, b, c$ ranging over *points* in the plane, a property $T(x, y, z)$ (ternary) such that $T(a, b, c)$ holds when the three points $a, b$ and $c$ are the vertex of a triangle, and a fuction $d(x, y)$ that gives us the *distance* between couples of points. Thus, we have : $\forall a \forall b \forall c(T(a, b, c) \rightarrow (d(a,b)+d(b,c)>d(a,c)))$. The converse will be : $\forall a \forall b \forall c((d(a,b)+d(b,c)>d(a,c)) \rightarrow T(a, b, c))$. 1/2

Comment: (of course, we have that $d$ gives us the *absolute value* of the distance). This will **not** be true in general; if we choose the three points $a(0,1)$, $b(0,3)$ and $c(0,2)$, we have that $d(a,b)+d(b,c)=3$ and $d(a,c)=1$ but the three points, being collinear, do not satisfy $T(a, b, c)$. 2/2

Comment: In order to convert the theorem, we have to formulate it with segments (and not points) with lenght satisfying the three possible inequalities. In this case, we can always move them in the plane in order to "conncet them" to form a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

From the second source you referenced: 
" A famous theorem of Euclidean geometry, the triangle inequality, states: 'The length of each
side of a triangle is less than the sum of the lengths of the other two.' A statement often
called the converse of the triangle inequality states: 'Given three lengths a, b and c such
that a + b > c, b + c > a and c + a > b, there exists a triangle with side lengths a, b and c.' "

From your statement of the triangle inequality, we may formulate it as the implication $P \implies Q $ where $P$ is the statement: There exists a triangle whose sides are $a$, $b,$ and $c$; $Q$ is the statement: $a + b > c$ (for any choice of $a,b,c$). Then the converse $Q \implies P$ is literally as formulated in the source above. That is, given that $a + b > c$, $b + c > a$, and $c + a > b$ (the statement $Q$), then there exists a triangle with side lengths $a,b$, and $c$ (the statement $P$).